# EXT JS 3.2- How can I make a Fieldset width not greater than the width as its content

Tags: extjs, fieldset

I have a panel holding a form. The form has  fieldsets enclosing it. However, the fieldset is displaying as the same size of the panel holding the form even when the form contents are much smaller than the panel. I won't the fieldset to not stretch to the containing panel. I only want fieldset to be only as big as the form it is enclosing.  However the fieldset takes the whole width of it's containing panel.

--Container for FormPanel

```
var win = new Ext.FormPanel({
    xtype: 'form',
    layout: 'form',
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    title: 'Testing',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        layout: 'hbox',
        autoHeight:true,
        autoWidth: false,
        title: 'Fieldset',
        defaults: {
            border: false,
            layout: 'form',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            labelSeparator: ''
        },
        items: [{
            items: new Ext.form.TextField({
                fieldLabel: 'Col1',
                name: 'col1',
                value: 'nothing',
            })
        }, {
            items: new Ext.form.TextField({
                fieldLabel: 'Col2',
                name: 'col2',
                value: 'something'
            })
        }]
    }, 
        new Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel: 'Col3',
            name: 'col3',
            value: 'anything'
        })
    ]
}).show();
```